# AVD_loader.cpp: failed to get a service for display 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

I am trying to play audio through a *WebView* built which is built in Swift. Upon playing the audio, sometimes it will play out and other times it'll play for ~2 seconds and stop. I then get an error in the Xcode log:

```
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGVA/AppleGVA-9.1.6.1/Sources/Slices/Driver/AVD_loader.cpp: failed to get a service for display 4
```

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: related? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10559#issuecomment-364939483

Comment: Try `app.disableHardwareAcceleration();`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: `app.disableHardwareAcceleration()`